# Can airline cancel part of a multi stop ticket but only offer refund for cancelled part of ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets

We have a return flight with BA in June 2020 from 
Newcastle to Heathrow to Boston (2 planes and connecting flights).

BA have emailed to say the Newcastle to London flight is cancelled and have offered a refund for this part of the trip.

However BA will not refund the remaining flights that make up this booking.

As the booking is Newcastle to Boston (via Heathrow)I now have no way of getting to Heathrow so I cannot see how they can selectively choose to refund one leg of the trip?????

What are my options?

---

BA have offered a refund for the
Newcastle to Heathrow journey (flight cancelled)
And offered a travel voucher for remainder of the trip.

---

Hi yes it was a single journey on the same day 
Outward 
Newcastle via Heathrow to Boston
Return
Boston via Heathrow to Newcastle.

Comment: Did you book Newcastle to Boston as a single ticket?

Comment: Please next time use the edit option and only use the 'answer' field if you have a real answer.

Comment: @Tilly Which Newcastle? I’m guessing Newcastle UK, but there are around 100 cities worldwide named Newcastle. If it is the UK, you do have the option of getting to LHR via train or car.

Comment: *I now have no way of getting to Heathrow*, we have trains in Europe ;-)

Answer (score 3):

According to its [General Conditions of Carriage](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/legal/british-airways/general-conditions-of-carriage) (which are fairly standard, and comply with EU261), British Airways should refund your money. This is a force majeure situation, so they aren't obligated to transport you from Newcastle to London, but they can't arbitrarily change your origin point and expect to keep your money, either. **The EU has [mandated](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davekeating/2020/04/06/airlines-must-issue-coronavirus-cancellation-refunds-says-eu/#1ade58fe6371) that airlines must pay out refunds, as has the [US Department of Transportation](https://www.transportation.gov/briefing-room/us-department-transportation-issues-enforcement-notice-clarifying-air-carrier-refund).**

BA is in crisis on account of the collapse in travel demand triggered by the COVID-19 outbreak. [Like other carriers](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-52105526), they are doing whatever they can to conserve cash and avoid a total collapse, and have been [for weeks](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-airlines-iata/refunds-row-escalates-as-airlines-warn-millions-of-jobs-at-risk-idUSKBN21P1S7); that includes denying or delaying refunds. At this point, the risk of regulator sanctions or customer [lawsuits](https://www.euronews.com/2020/04/28/european-airlines-could-face-class-action-suit-over-unpaid-coronavirus-refunds) or angry Tweets are irrelevant compared to surviving for another week, and BA has been one of the more conspicuously bad actors in this, as [widely reported](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/04/26/british-airways-customers-struggling-get-refund-cancelled-flights/). Your options are limited.

1. **Call the airline.**
   According to their [Coronavirus travel and service updates](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/incident/coronavirus/latest-information#refund) page, and as also reported anecdotally, for a refund, you will need to get an agent on the phone and press them on the matter. It may be very difficult to get an agent on the phone, but if they have shut down operations at the airport there is no point in going there (which might also violate any orders against non-essential travel). If you have frequent flyer elite status, work those channels first.
2. **Make an insurance claim.**
   Depending on when you bought your ticket and what is stated in the policy, you may qualify for compensation for trip interruption from your travel insurance provider, and you should contact the insurance company to file a claim. It isn't easy to may your insurance company pay even in good times, so this will also take an investment of time. If you didn't buy travel insurance, well, that's that.
3. **File a chargeback.**
   You can also contact your credit card company and [attempt a chargeback](https://www.msn.com/en-us/finance/personalfinance/travel-dilemmas-4-steps-to-a-travel-related-refund-from-your-credit-card-no-skipping-steps-1-3/ar-BB13jdWH). Given the volume of people attempting to do this, the credit card issuer may also push back.

If you're willing to cancel the whole trip and accept a voucher for future travel, that option should still be available through BA's website, but I fully sympathize with a lack of faith in BA.

Comment: This is essentially the same for almost any airline right now: You are legally entitled, but they are strapped for cash and simply won't pay. At least there is a good chance that most European governments will prop up their airlines, so you can at least hope that the voucher would still be valid afterwards. If you want cash, it's going to be a long and tedious fight - airlines seem to hope they can drag this out until flights restart...